# Can I close the current open window (python)

Tags: python, window

I would like to know if there's a command that closes the current file, by that I mean:

opened Hello.py -> In the middle of the file the window shuts down (not by an error)

Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "close current file"? Who opened it? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I managed to understand the question correctly, then you can use `sys.exit()`

```
import sys
import time

for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print i
    if i == 5:
      sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

sys.exit()
```

this will exit out of python. for example if you are running the program from the command line like:

```
python program.py
```

and in your code it coems across sys.exit()

it will boot you back to the command line

if the program is a standalone, it will close the program, just like clicking the red x